# Firefox moves img down one line

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, firefox

I recently added an image after the text in the first column of a table. The image is right aligned.

Chrome and Safari display the text and image on the same line. Firefox right aligns the image, but moves it down one line. There is plenty of room in the cells to display both the text and image on a single line.

How do I make Firefox display the image on the same line as the text?

Here is a plunker that demonstrates the issue: http://embed.plnkr.co/2pdsJeY3TQ1MKETQqAHp/preview

Comment: The plunker does not resolve the image urls, but the misalignment in Firefox occurs whether or not the images are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple solutions.

**One:** Add this style:

```
table {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

**Two:** Place the `img` before the text within the HTML:

```
<td class="label-text">
  <img class="image-symbol" src="{{symbols[key].image}}" 
       alt="{{symbols[key].symbolName}}">
  {{playerDecisionMetadata[key].label}}
</td>
```

This appears to be a bug in Firefox, because according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position):

> 8. A floating box must be placed as high as possible.

Comment: The table styling suggestion had no effect. Moving the img before the text had the desired effect in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Thanks!